# Is there a PHP script that can convert HTML table data to various formats?

Tags: php, file-format

Using PHP, I can convert MySQL data or static table data to csv, Excel, JSON, MySQL etc but is there a useful conversion script or tool that can convert table data into other formatted/styled formats such as PDF and/or JPG/PNG using the PHP GD Library or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [this](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/) before to turn a HTML table into a PDF. I generated the table from a MySQL query.

Comment: Looks like this has moved to http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/ and I'd be interested to see some examples similar to this but for images. There's a lot of "screenshot" software apps I guess works in the interim...

Answer (score 0):

To export to Excel I use the following code:

```
<?php

/*  Define our Database and Table Info */


$username="";
$password="";
$database="";
$table="";


mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$select = "SELECT * FROM $table";                
$export = mysql_query($select);
$fields = mysql_num_fields($export);

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $header .= mysql_field_name($export, $i) . "\t";
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($export)) {
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value) {                                            
        if ((!isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {
            $value = "\t";
        } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim($line)."\n";
}
$data = str_replace("\r","",$data);

if ($data == "") {
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mailinglist.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data"; 
?>
```

Now be careful with how you include this.  It's using the Headers to send the file information to force a download,  by doing this you can't have any white space anywhere before these headers are sent otherwise it may throw an error.   I usually have this link open as a new window to prevent anything from happening... Again this is just a pretty basic script that can be expanded greatly.  Hope this Helps!

Comment: It could be useful to combine with a csv, xls converter of which I do have implementations, I'd like to add pdf and jpg to the mix also with a simple drop down or get variable posted to determine the output file format. Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: As far as PDF I normally end up using a library like: http://www.fpdf.org/ (FPDF)  it's pretty easy to impliment and pretty simple to use.   I know there is scripting to make JPEGs on the fly as well as flash but I haven't really experimented with them too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  

/  Define our Database and Table Info /  

$username="";  
$password="";  
$database="";  
$table="";  

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);  
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");  
$select = "SELECT * FROM $table";                  
$export = mysql_query($select);  
$fields = mysql_num_fields($export);  

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {  
    $header .= mysql_field_name($export, $i) . ",";  
}  

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($export)) {  
    $line = '';  
    foreach($row as $value) {                                              
        if ((!isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {  
            $value = ",";  
        } else {  
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);  
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . ",";  
        }  
        $line .= $value;  
    }  
    $data .= trim($line)."n";  
}  
$data = str_replace("r","",$data);  

if ($data == "") {  
    $data = "n(0) Records Found!n";                          
}  

header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mailinglist.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Expires: 0");  
print "$headern$data";   
?>
```

Comment: You could add a description of what your code does to make your answer clearer